# on button click change content from an external div

Tags: php, html, ajax, wordpress

I have this button in the backend of wordpress and if it is clicked it should change the content from a div in one file from my theme. I am probably very far away with my code from where I should be...

```
<input type="submit" value="load()" id="start_chat" /> //the button
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

 $.ajaxSetup ({  
            cache: false  
        });  

    var loadUrl = "facut_mine3.php";  // the file where there is only a new content for the div #eu_la
    $("#start_chat").click(function(){  
        $("#eu_la").load('http://www.fattorefamiglia.com/wp-content/themes/child_care_creative/layout_home_page2.php').html(loadUrl);  //this is the file that I want to change, with the div #eu_la
    });  
</script>
```

Of course, nothing changes when I click the button. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: put the error handling codes in your ajax call to figure out what error you are getting..

Comment: you mean I cannot change the content of a file from a different file? there is no solution?

Comment: @Ashish I don't know how to do that and I can't find how to do it on google. do you have a link?

Comment: instead of $().load() use $.ajax()  you can find more about $.ajax on http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Making it simple. You have some content on a page. When you click on a button, you need to display some other content on that place. Is this your ultimate goal??

Comment: no, I want to change the content from a different page. so: button on the backend -> click -> change structure on the frontend. 2 different files...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To allow cross-domain Ajax requests set up an **.htaccess** file in the ROOT, containing following content:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
```

Also see:

- enable-cors.org
- code.google.com/p/html5security/wiki/CrossOriginRequestSecurity

Comment: I did that, but nothing happened. btw, there was some code in that file, I just put your code with the other...